# Selenium un-enable to find element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2, chromedriver, chrome

I have been through every selenium related page on here but not much else I can really try.

I am trying to click on the text link but It gives me 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable'

I have tried finding the element by:
xpath
csselector
etc

There are no frames in this particular html page so it cant be an issue of switching frames.

I have tried getting by tagname("a") also div class "content" then search elements inside but to no avail.

```
<div class="content"><br><span style="font-size:20px"><b><a href="https://mmashare.fullfight.video/viewtopic.php?f=36&amp;t=1544">VIDEO</a></b></span><div class="responsive-show" style="display:none"><style type="text/css">
```

This is the html page in full.

https://mmashare.fullfight.video/viewtopic.php?t=1545&p=1545#p1545

Ps this is not my homework
I would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks in advance guys.

Update:

here is the code I have I am currently trying

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String url = "https://mmashare.fullfightvideo.eu/";
    driver.get(url);
    String li = "";

        Thread.sleep(15 * 1000);
        //https://mmashare.fullfightvideo.eu/ that clicks on first link
        // and sends user to second page
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]/strong/span/div/ul/li[1]/span/a")).click();

        Thread.sleep(15 * 1000);
        //clicking the video text link on the second page https://mmashare.fullfight.video/viewtopic.php?t=1545&p=1545#p1545
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span/b/a")).click();
```

Comment: one question..I just tried it with the xpath=//div[@id='post_content1545']/h3/a  - could you please have a try? For my understanding, you just tried it with the div class? Did you tried it with xpath option?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the first thing I tried....I also tried with xpath and full xpath as well

Comment: @Davidito hi please provide the code you have tried so far

Comment: I tried making the url go directly to the second page and see if it find the element and it does. However, when the base url is the first page and I click one element on the first page to the second page it no longer can find the element on the second page.

Comment: Please put the code , if it's going to the base url then it's not chrome driver issue

Comment: Hi @Davidito so you are able to open browser and navigate to home page ? .

Comment: @PDHide So the base url ''https://mmashare.fullfightvideo.eu/" works...however its when I get to the second page I cant find the element I want to click on. If I go directly to the second page "https://mmashare.fullfight.video/viewtopic.php?t=1545&p=1545#p1545" and click the element it works, but as I stated before when I add the first url and go through the first element to the second page and then try to click that element from there, thats when I cant find the element.

Comment: Hi you have to switch tab before getting the element

Comment: as the second page is opening in a new tab

Comment: @PDHide its worked! come to think of it I should have known....silly me. Lesson learned, thank you my friend.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer and upvote, i have already answered it

Comment: Just click tick sign near to my answer and click the up arrow

Answer (score 3):

**It seems the second page is opening in a new tab, please switch the tab before interacting with the page:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]/strong/span/div/ul/li[1]/span/a")).click();
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
Thread.sleep(15 * 1000);

            //clicking the video text link on the second page https://mmashare.fullfight.video/viewtopic.php?t=1545&p=1545#p1545
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span/b/a")).click();
driver.close();   

//To switch back
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
```

**Note:** Just print the tabs variable and see the content to switch properly

Answer (score 1):

For of all thank everyone for your help!

The answer was quite simple and I hope some of the senior members dont get mad.

In order to access the elements on the second page all I that needed to be done is switch to the correct tab.

```
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
    //clicking the video text link on the second page 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span/b/a")).click();
```

Thanks again everyone, lesson learned!

Comment: If you ended up getting the answer from PDHide, then you should upvote and accept that answer - this is essentially a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 0):

Check your selenium and chrome version.
I don't think the issue is related to locator. I tried it in my local and it's working fine. I used xpath **//a[text()='VIDEO']**

Here's the log. At the last part, you will notice that it locates the element and click it.

pool-1-thread-1: Executing get parameters: 
{"url":"https://mmashare.fullfight.video/viewtopic.php?t=1545&p=1545#p1545"}

pool-1-thread-1: command: get[ param-1: {url=https://mmashare.fullfight.video/viewtopic.php?t=1545&p=1545#p1545}] Result: null

pool-1-thread-1: Executing findElement parameters: {"using":"xpath","value":"//a[text()='VIDEO']"}

pool-1-thread-1: command: findElement[ param-1: {value=//a[text()='VIDEO'], using=xpath}] Result: id: 0.6429585374922933-1

pool-1-thread-1: Executing clickElement element: By.xpath: //a[text()='VIDEO'] parameters: {"id":"0.6429585374922933-1"}

Comment: Hey Millie thanks for the help! I am using chrome verison 79.0.3945.36 which is one before that newest, curious to know which version you are using ?

Comment: @Davidito How about your selenium version? I'm using chrome 79.0.3945.88